# series' convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(1-x^n)$ converges for $x \in (-1,1]$. Evidently, the series converges trivially for $x=0$. The series also converges for $x \in (0,1]$, because in such case, $\sum x^n(1-x^n) \le \sum x^n$, and $\sum x^n$ converges. How to prove the convergence for $x \in (-1,0)$?

Comment: Both $\sum x^n$ and $\sum x^{2n}$ converge for $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: expand the products and split the series as the difference of two convergent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series also trivially converges for $x=1$, the second term in the product being identically zero.

Otherwise

$$|x^n(1-x^n)| \leq |x|^n + |x|^{2n} \leq 2|x|^n$$

and so for $x \in (-1,1)$ the series converges, since $\sum |x|^n$ converges.